# Generator of random words without repeating letters without searching

Tags: algorithm, random, generator, permutation, combinatorics

What parameters are passed to the generator:

- x - word number;
- N is the size of the alphabet;
- L is the length of the output word.

It is necessary to implement a non-recursive algorithm that will return a word based on the three parameters passed.

Alphabet - Latin letters in alphabetical order, caps.

For `N = 5`, `L = 3` we construct a correspondence of `x` to words:

- 0: ABC
- 1: ABD
- 2: ABE
- 3: ACB
- 4: ACD
- 5: ACE
- 6: ADB
- 7: ADC
- 8 ADE
- 9: AEB
- 10 AEC
- 11 AED
- 12 BAC
- ...

My implementation of the algorithm works for L = 1; 2. But errors appear on L = 3. The algorithm is based on shifts when accessing the alphabet. The `h` array stores the indices of the letters in the new dictionary (from which the characters that have already entered the word are excluded). Array `A` stores casts of indices `h` into the original dictionary (adds indents for each character removed from the alphabet to the left). Thus, in the end, array `A` stores Permutations without repetitions.

```
private static String getS (int x, int N, int L) {
    String s = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQ";
    String out = "";

    int [] h = new int [N];
    int [] A = new int [N];

    for (int i = 0; i <L; i ++) {
        h [i] = (x / (factory (N - 1 - i) / factory (N - L)))% (N-i);

        int sum = h [i];

        for (int j = 0; j <i; j ++)
            sum + = ((h [i]> = h [j])? 1: 0);
        
        A [i] = sum;
        out + = s.charAt (A [i]);

    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match your description. Do you need a random word, or the x'th word in alphabetical order?

Comment: @Dave probably yes. I mean x is random but there is a one word foreach x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a random word of length L: keep the alphabet in an array of size N, and get a random word of length L by swapping the i'th element for a random element in i to N-1 for i in [0, L-1].

To generate the x'th word of length L in alphabetical order: Note that for a word of size L made up of distinct letters from an alphabet of size N, there are (N-1)! / (N-L)! words starting with any given letter.

E.g., N=5, L=3, alphabet = ABCDE. The number of words starting with A (or any letter) is 4! / 2! = 12. These are all the ordered N-L-length subsets of the available N-1 letters.

So the first letter of word(x, N, L) is the x / ((N-1)! / (N-L)!) letter of the alphabet (zero-indexed).

You can then build your word recursively.

E.g., word(15, 5, 3, ABCDE): The first letter is 15 / (4! / 2!) = 15 / 12) = 1, so B.

We get the second letter recursively: word((15 % (4! / 2!), 4, 2, ACDE) = word(3, 4, 2, ACDE). Since 3 / (3! / 2!) = 3 / 3 = 1, the second letter is C.

Third letter: word(3%3, 3, 1, ADE) = word(0, 3, 1, ADE) = A.

```
0. ABC
1. ABD
2. ABE
3. ACB
4. ACD
5. ACE
6. ADB
7. ADC
8. ADE
9. AEB
10. AEC
11. AED
12. BAC
13. BAD
14. BAE
15. BCA
```

Comment: thanks for answer! I think it could be the solution, but I fear we cannot implement it by code without recursions...

Comment: @D7ILeucoH Instead of recursing, you could keep a set of the letters that have been used so far, and get the k'th letter by iterating through the alphabet, skipping over used letters. That adds O(N*L), but is effectively linear if L is bounded (e.g. <= 26).

Comment: my solution is actually computing correct indexes in a new alphabet. But there are issue to convert this index into the index of initial alphabet

Answer (score 1):

A different approach.  You have a list of five letters: [ABCDE] and you have some words made from three of those letters with no repeats.  Hence each letter is either included (1) or not included (0) in the word.  That maps each word onto a five bit integer with only three bits set.  In more general terms, you have each word mapping onto an L bit integer with N bits set.

That suggests running through the L bit integers, counting the number of set bits.  Keep track of how many integers have N bits set.  When you reach the required position, translate the integer back into a word: 22 -> 10110 -> ACD.

There are various tricks to speed up counting set bits using some logic operations if the simple approach isn't fast enough.

ETA: I should have made clear that you scan in reverse order from 0b11111 down to 0b00000.  That matches with alphabetical order.  ABC (11100) comes before CDE (00111).

Comment: It is fast maybe but it is not the solution. Creating a map is poor, and 10110 is ignoring any other combinations of the letters

Comment: You are  not ignoring any relevant combinations.  Only combinations with the correct number of letters are counted.  See my ETA on ordering.